# Genres/ Subjects/ Categories in epub's metadata

Tags: epub, metadata

What is the proper way to define genre in epub's metadata? (in `OEBPS/content.opf` file.)

I can't google the definition, just some obviousness mentions like "*It may also include many other things such as ... the genre*" ([link](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Metadata))

And, by the way, where can I find the current list of literary genres? (I found one in the [wiki](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_genre), but I'm not sure, is it applicable here or not.)

**UPD** 28.12.2019

I found in some downloaded epubs that genres are listed in several tags called `subject` from **DDI-Codebook** namespace, e.g.:

```
    <package xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" ...>
    ...
    <dc:title>A Journey to the Centre of the Earth</dc:title>
    ...
    <dc:subject>Science fiction</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject>Adventure stories</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject>Earth (Planet) -- Core -- Fiction</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject>Voyages, Imaginary -- Fiction</dc:subject>
```

On the ddialliance.org I found a [corresponding page](https://ddialliance.org/Specification/DDI-Codebook/2.5/XMLSchema/field_level_documentation_files/schemas/dc_xsd/elements/subject.html) with this obscure description:

> Namespace: http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/
>
> Type: SimpleLiteral, inherited from any
>
> Content: mixed (allows character data), 1 attribute
>
> Subst.Gr: may substitute for element any
>
> Defined: globally in dc.xsd; see XML source
>
> Used: never

Is it really correct to define genres in this tags? Or is it "de facto" standard without strict rule?

Answer (score 2):

This field comes from the Dublin Core (DC) metadata standard, which is useful for interoperability between software and databases. I don't think there has emerged an accepted way to use DC metadata for ebook reading systems.

One idea might be to go with BISAC categories (as [listed here](https://bisg.org/page/bisacedition)). My memory could be mistaken, but I don't think the reading systems process these values in any meaningful way, (wouldn't that be nice if they did!) BTW, I seem to recall that Google Play required that you use BISAC codes when selling through them. For the DC metadata, don't use the alphanumeric value of the BISAC,  just use a simple phrase based on BISAC values.

Here's a [book marketing guy explaining BISAC vs. Amazon's categories](https://k-lytics.com/bisac-codes-vs-amazon-kindle-storefront-categories/). Here's  [more by this same book marketing guy.](https://kindlepreneur.com/how-to-choose-the-best-kindle-ebook-kdp-category/)